# VariantSection's Is link field type is wrongly mapped to Droplist in SXA 1.8

Tags: sxa

Variant Section

Recently I was playing with Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8 for new features. **I discovered that Is Link field is wrongly mapped to Droplist Type having Source Location. I think field type should be the checkbox instead of droplist**.

I verified the backend code and it expects the boolean value for **Is Link** property.

Is this a bug in new version or enums are missing or it's safe to change the type from **droplist** to **checkbox**?

Comment: I would contact Sitecore Support Helpdesk -> https://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/login

Answer (score 4):

`IsLink` field is now a dropdown with the following options:

[image]

SXA 1.8 has a bug, those dropdown options were not added to the package. As far as I known there is already a hotfix ready for it. Please contact Sitecore support.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Sitecore.

Sitecore Public Reference No: 326111
You can download the package from my drive https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FX1mUQzU158l2Gutnr1C7N9-n5uhJvR-

Thanks, Dawid and Peter.